# Could Dracule Mihawk mistake a small child for an animal?

Tags: one-piece

I've been wondering about the extent of Mihawk's observational haki. Do you think he would ever observe a weak human child and think it's a small mammal? He doesn't seem to interested in weaklings.

Answer (score 1):

Since Observation Haki can also read minds, I doubt Mihawk could confuse anyone sentient, as weak, frail and small as they could be, with an actual animal.